# Como obter penúltimo registro de uma data no Oracle usando consulta SQL

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Preciso puxar as informações de acordo com a penúltima data, atualmente, esse `MAX(S2.DTMUDANCA)` está trazendo o último, porém não é necessário para mim, somente o último. Tentei algumas questões, mas ainda estou com dúvidas, tentei comparar com um novo select, sem sucesso.
Segue abaixo o select:

```
SELECT A.CODCOLIGADA, A.CHAPA, A.CODSITUACAO, A.CODTIPO, A.NOME AS COLABORADOR, F.NOME AS FUNÇÃO, S.DESCRICAO AS SETOR,
       (SELECT MAX(S2.DTMUDANCA) FROM RM.PFHSTSEC S2 WHERE S2.CODCOLIGADA = HS.CODCOLIGADA AND S2.CHAPA = HS.CHAPA) AS DATA_SEÇÃO_ATUAL,
       To_Char(A.DATAADMISSAO,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATA_ADMISSÃO, To_Char(A.DATADEMISSAO,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATA_DEMISSÃO,
       TO_CHAR(HS.DTMUDANCA,'DD/MM/YYYY') AS DATA, (SELECT sa.descricao FROM rm.psecao sa WHERE sa.codcoligada = hs.codcoligada AND sa.codigo = hs.codsecao)
  FROM RM.PFHSTSEC HS, RM.PFUNC A, RM.PFUNCAO F, RM.PSECAO S
  WHERE
    HS.CODCOLIGADA = A.CODCOLIGADA
    AND A.CHAPA = HS.CHAPA
    AND HS.CODCOLIGADA IN (1,5,7,8)
    AND A.CODCOLIGADA = F.CODCOLIGADA
    AND A.CODFUNCAO = F.CODIGO
    AND A.CODCOLIGADA = S.CODCOLIGADA
    AND A.CODSECAO = S.CODIGO

  AND HS.DTMUDANCA >= '01/11/2019'
  ORDER BY A.CODCOLIGADA, A.NOME, hs.dtmudanca
```

[Retorno do select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCHUo.png)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aj9id.png)

Answer (score 2):

A função de agregação `MAX()` vai retornar apenas a maior data, para trazer "as duas, três, etc maiores" é preciso *"rankear"* as datas. Isso é possível usando `ROW_NUMBER()` e `OVER`.

`ROW_NUMBER()` retorna o número de uma linhas, mas se usada em combinação com `OVER`, vai retornar o número da linha de acordo com o critério dentro de `OVER`.

Imagine por exemplo que tem as datas:
10/11/2022
15/11/2022
01/12/2022

Se fizer um `select` assim: `SELECT DATA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DATA) NUMERO`, vai retornar:

```
DATA        NUMERO  
==================  
10/11/2022  1  
15/11/2022  2    
01/12/2022  3
```

Da mesma forma que, se usar `ORDER BY DATA DESC`, vai interter a ordem, 1 será a maior, no exemplo a última, e assim por diante. Logo, se fizer um `WHERE NUMERO < 3` vai trazer as 2 maiores datas, e se quiser só a penúltima basta fazer `WHERE NUMERO = 2` :)

Veja aqui um exemplo funcionando: [http://sqlfiddle.com/](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ca370/1)

E a query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
     SELECT COD, DTMUDANCA,
            ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (ORDER BY DTMUDANCA DESC) ORDEM
      FROM Teste
      )
WHERE ORDEM < 3;
```